# Assigning a user-entered char to a variable

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having a few issues successfully storing a user entered `char` to a variable, the variable which then needs to be used in a different part of the program.

The program in question is supposed to do the following things:

- Take a set of user entered values
- Place those values into an array of predetermined size
- Prompt the user if they would like to see the array
- If 'Y', pretty print the array.

I will show you the second part of the program here, in code fragment form, since the first part (placing the values into the array) works fine:

```
char input, confirm;
printf("Would you like to view the array? Y/N: ");
    while ((input = getchar()) != EOF){
        confirm = putchar(input);
    if (confirm == 'Y'){
        printf("[");
        for (i = 0; i < maxvals; i++){
            if (i != maxvals - 1){
                printf("%d,", A[i]);
            }
            else{
                printf("%d", A[i]);
            }
        }
        printf("]");
    }
    printf("\n");
```

All variables are obviously pre-declared. Lines 2 and 3 are where I'm having an issue right now.

When I try to run the program, I get:

```
$ arrays.exe
Enter as many as 10 values, ^D to end
1 2 3
^D
3 values read into array
Would you like to view the array? Y/N: ♦
Y
Y
```

Note the program just repeats what the user entered. I tried this also (in place of the while loop):

```
confirm = getchar();
```

But this just terminates the program. I'm also worried that my `if (confirm == "Y")` line won't work, but based on my previous programming experience I think it should?

I'm pretty sure I've given all the necessary code but if you want the entire program please tell me so I can edit this.

EDIT:

No one mentioned scanf. It solved the problem. Here is the working code for future reference:

```
while (scanf("%c", &confirm) == 1){
    if (confirm == 'Y'){
    printf("[");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (i != n - 1){
            printf("%d,", A[i]);
         }
         else{
            printf("%d", A[i]);
         }
    }
    printf("]");
    break;
    }
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Pay attention to your compiler output, this code has errors that must cause error messages to be generated. If you're not seeing them then turn up the compiler warning level.

Comment: "All variables are obviously pre-declared" - obviously `input` is not, if you're getting that error. And `getchar()` returns an `int`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Okay, you were right there, that was my bad, I had forgot to declare input. I'm still having issues, which I've added to my question now

Comment: a newline character will be read just before EOF. so the confirm value will be a newline. Of course, newline is not 'Y' so the print operation never happens.  also, the user is just as likely to enter a lower case 'n' or 'y' or any other keyboard available character.

Comment: the function getchar() returns an int, not a char.  and EOF is an int, so will never match. a char variable

Comment: @user3629249 so if getchar() returns an int, how am I supposed to assign the char to confirm?

Comment: this line: 'while ((input = getchar()) != EOF){' will skip right over any 'Y' or 'N' and might never exit the loop.  There is a small problem with the logic in that area because erronous input should be informing the user of the invalid input.  however, for the while statement, suggest: 'while( input = getchar() && !(input == 'Y' || input == 'N') );

Comment: just do a comfirm = input;  the conversion will 'automagically' work.  Or better. read the character directly into 'confirm'

Comment: what do you expect this line to do: 'confirm = putchar(input);'  in good conditions, confirm will contain the value from input.  However, if an error occurs, confirm will contain EOF.... IF confirm were an int.  otherwise confirm will (at best) contain 0xFF

Comment: @user3629249 "EOF is an `int`, so will never match a `char` variable" is not necessarily true.  Assume `char` is 8-bit signed and `EOF == -1`.  Then when `EOF` is returned from `getchar()` and saved in a `char`, the `char` has a value of `-1` and does compare equally with `EOF`.  The trouble is that if a value 255 is returned, it also is saved in a `char` as `-1` and compares equally with `EOF`.  IAC, agree the value returned from `getchar()` should be an `int` and not `char` for correct functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You say it didn't work, but you don't say what the symptoms of not working were.  That might help.  In any case, two things I see as probable problems:

1. `putchar(input)` is not doing anything useful.  `putchar` does not write values to variables (you are trying to assign to `confirm`), it writes to the standard output of the program (not at all the same thing).  I don't think you want to use `putchar` at all.
2. If `confirm` is a `char`, you want to compare to `'Y'`, which is a character, not `"Y"`, which is a string.  It might help to see how `confirm` is declared.

Comment: I've edited my post with the details you asked for. Compiler output has been added and I showed how input and confirm were declared in the code fragment.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified example of what you are trying to do.  There is no way to stop this loop as the eof character is '\0' unless you are reading input from a file (aside from cntrl+c or the exit button if you are working on a console application).  A character has to be compared to a letter in single quotes.  Also, as the previous poster mentioned, putchar is not doing what you anticipate.
Here is the documentation on that function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/putchar/

```
int main()
{
    char input, confirm;
    printf("Would you like to view the array? Y/N: ");
    while ((input = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (input == 'Y'){
            printf("!");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `input` should be an `int`, not a `char`. And you have an unused variable `confirm`.

Answer (score -1):

```
here is your code, cleaned up some
and not using a 'input' variable
and not using a call to putchar()
and 'confirm' properly declared as an int


// this assumes that A[] and maxvals and i are already defined and set

int confirm;
printf("Would you like to view the array? Y/N: ");

while ((confirm = getchar() && !( 'Y' == confirm || 'N' == confirm ) && EOF != confirm  )
{
    if( EOF == confirm ) exit(1);
    else printf( "invalid input: please enter: 'Y' or 'N'");
} // end while

// when get here, confirm contains 'Y' or 'N'
if ( 'Y' == confirm )
{
    printf("[");
    for (i = 0; i < maxvals; i++)
    {
        if (i != maxvals - 1)
        {
            printf("%d,", A[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d", A[i]);
        } // end if
    } // end for
    printf("]");
} // end if
printf("\n");
```

Comment: `()` not balanced in `while ((confirm = getchar() && !( 'Y' == confirm || 'N' == confirm ) && EOF != confirm  )`  and `EOF != confirm` prevents the body's `if( EOF == confirm )` from ever being true.  Suggest reviewing code.

Comment: @chux how would you suggest he fix it?

Comment: @PythonNewb: obviously, by putting the missing close parenthesis after the `getchar()` so the assignment occurs properly.  It's probably reasonable to stop the loop if the input character is a null byte, but it isn't immediately obvious that it was the intention.